# Unity Container exception – You cannot have more than one dynamic module in each dynamic assembly in this version of the runtime

Tags: c#, .net-core, migration, unity-container

I've got a project that I need to Migrate from .NET Framework to .NET Core. After migrating it I've noticed an exception –

> Unity.Exceptions.ResolutionFailedException   HResult=0x80131500
> Message=Resolution of the dependency failed, type =
> 'LanDocs.ExchangeSystem.Server.Interfaces.IExchangeDataHandler', name
> = '(none)'. Exception occurred while: while resolving. Exception is: InvalidOperationException - You cannot have more than one dynamic
> module in each dynamic assembly in this version of the runtime.

What might be the issue and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out myself and decided to share the solution here since I haven't found anything helpful while struggling with it.
The issue was with Policy Injection – once I've removed the entire section everything worked well.
But the problem was the version of version of nuget package. I've had Unity.Interception with version 5.5.3 and Unity with version 5.8.6. Once I've changed both versions to 5.11.1 everything worked well on .NET Core.